# gdb : findind every jumps to an address

Tags: gdb, memory-address, disassembly

I'm trying to understand a small binary using gdb but there is something I can't find a way to achieve : how can I find the list of jumps that point to a specified address?
I have a small set of instructions in the disassembled code and I want to know where it is called.
I first thought about searching the corresponding instruction in .text, but since there are many kind of jumps, and address can be relative, this can't work.

Is there a way to do that?

Alternatively, if I put a breakpoint on this address, is there a way to know the address of the previous instruction (in this case, the jump)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is some *subroutine* being called from other places, then it must respect some ABI while it's called. 
Depending on a CPU used, the return address (and therefore a place from where it was called) will be stored somewhere (on stack or in some registers). If you replace original code with the one that examines this, you can create a list of return addresses. Or simpler, as you suggested, if you use gdb and put a breakpoint at that routine, you can see from where it was called by using a bt command.

If it was actual jump (versus a "jump to subroutine") that led you there (which I doubt, if it's called from many places, unless it's a kind of longjmp/setjmp), then you will probably not be able to determine where this was called from, unless the CPU you are using allows you to trace the execution in some way.

Comment: Yes I am talking about a kind of longjump, but you are right, I just have to follow the jump at the end which returns to the initial "function". Could have thought about it, but I was used to this feature "find jumps pointing here" in OllyDbg. Could be useful to have this in gdb though.

Another solution, as you pointed out, is to use the backtrace, but it leads to the parent function of the one I am looking for (since the jump didn't put anything on the callstack). Can be a solution anyway.

**Thanks for your reply!**